# Find youtube iframe and replace it with custom code

Tags: php, jquery, youtube-api, preg-replace, youtube-javascript-api

I have a wp site that in a lot of posts i am using youtube videos embeded with the clasic iframe.
Is possible to find the iframe div inside post and replace it with a custom youtube code?
I want to use the code bellow to control youtube video. When it starts, when it is finished.

The code that i have in my posts is:

```
<iframe width="824" height="464" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/eEqIBzxHjiA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And i want to replace it with:

```
<script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'eEqIBzxHjiA',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
          alert ('FInished');

        }
    }

</script>
```

Thank you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use shortcodes**
1. The WordPress Rich Editor might strip out JavaScript src tags so best is to write a little plugin that defines a shortcode e.g. [myyoutube id=eEqIBzxHjiA] and use that one from now on. Probably you want to define a javascript .js file that holds the main code and include that in each page where the shortcode is present. So all of the above except the player ID will be in the included .js file that you define in the shortcut code. only the playerId is then a call to the javascript function.

**legacy**
2. For all the existing entries: probably the fastest to use a sql command on the database posts table and replace all entries matching the regex above with the new shortcode tag. (fastest way)